# Loading File on Heroku Server Start?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have two questions. I have deployed a flask application to heroku and everything is working correctly. Do I need to uncomment the `app.run(debug=True)` line in my `app.py` file:

```
# Run App
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -k gevent app:app
```

I'm assuming heroku ignores the one in the `app.py` file, but I'm not sure. My second question is that I'm loading a model and need to run the following line
`classifier = job lib.load('myClassifier.pkl')`, but have no clue where I put this. I want to be able to access the `classifier` object from my flask app file `app.py`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to uncomment the `app.run(debug=True)`. In the Procfile you can see `app:app`. That means that gunicorn will import the `app` WSGI object from the `app` file and run it.

If you want to run a task after a deploy, Heroku provides hooks to do so. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks

Comment: Thanks jumbopap. But I'm not sure if hooks is what I'm after. I essentially want to define a variable from a loaded file. Right now I define it before `app.run(debug=True)` but not sure if this will work once deployed. Or where the best place do it it is.